# Segfault from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0

Tags: c, cryptography, openssl, segmentation-fault, aes

I am trying to write a little program to encrypt something with OpenSSL and AES in CBC mode.
Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>

// main entrypoint
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    unsigned char *aes_key = malloc(32*sizeof(unsigned char));
        printf("Enter a 32 char key\n");
        scanf("%s", aes_key);
        if ((sizeof(aes_key)/sizeof(aes_key[0])) != 8) {
            fprintf(stderr,"you didn't write 32 char\n");
            return -1;
        }


    uint64_t msg = 30849384302932039;

    /* generate input with a given length */
    unsigned char *aes_input = malloc(100*sizeof(unsigned char));
    sprintf(aes_input, "%lu", msg);

    /* init vector */
    unsigned char *iv = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) *AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
    RAND_bytes(iv, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);

    // buffers for encryption and decryption
    unsigned char *enc_out = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*16);
    sprintf(enc_out, "%d", 0);

    AES_KEY enc_key, dec_key;
    AES_set_encrypt_key(aes_key, 32, &enc_key);
    AES_cbc_encrypt(aes_input, enc_out, 16, &enc_key, iv, AES_ENCRYPT);

    printf("original:\t + %s\n",aes_input);
    printf("encrypt:\t + %s\n",enc_out);

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with `gcc -g test.c -lcrypto -o test` but when I run it, I get a segmentation fault and gdb indicates me :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a7b9a0 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

After trying to debug it, I found that the line `AES_cbc_encrypt(aes_input, enc_out, 15, &enc_key, iv, AES_ENCRYPT);` is responsible of the segfaut... But, all arguments seem initialized, I tried to print their values and I didn't get any problem ?

So I don't realy get what I am doing wrong, could someone help me ? Thank you very much :)

Comment: segmentation fault has so many reasons, there are no call stack displayed ? first you need to debug your program to see at which line it crashes ...

Comment: Well I just made it and it seems that it is the line  `AES_cbc_encrypt(aes_input, enc_out, 15, &enc_key, iv AES_ENCRYPT)` that makes my program crash. I will modify my post to indicate it

Comment: You need to go further more inside that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unsigned char *aes_key = malloc(32*sizeof(unsigned char));
...
if ((sizeof(aes_key)/sizeof(aes_key[0])) != 8) {
```

This is not getting the size of the array (32), but the size of a pointer to `unsigned char`.

Same for

```
const uint64_t encslength = ((sizeof(aes_input)/sizeof(aes_input[0]) + AES_BLOCK_SIZE) / AES_BLOCK_SIZE) * AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
```

Take a look to [Question 7.28 of C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/malloc/sizeof.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well so that means that my test is useless, right ? But I don't know how to test it properly... Anyway I don't think that's the source of my segfault

Comment: The source of your segfault is probably `const uint64_t encslength = ((sizeof(aes_input)/sizeof(aes_input[0]) ...` because `aes_input` is a pointer (not an array)

Comment: Well I replaced `encslength` by `100` in my code and I still have a segfault at the line `AES_cbc_encrypt(aes_input, enc_out, 15, &enc_key, iv AES_ENCRYPT)`. However thank you for your help

Comment: My bad, I changed it to 16 but still the same problem. I will try to check more precisely the function `AES_cbc_encrypt`

Comment: @AlterMann AES block size is always 128 bits / 16 bytes.